How to add a period after a theorem number?
I'm using the newtheorem command to label "Problems" in a journal manuscript (using this template).  However, there is no period after the number assigned to each Problem.  How can I get periods after the Problem number?
This is essentially the opposite of this question, which asked how to remove the periods, except I am not using the amsthm package, as it throws LaTeX Error: Command \openbox already defined. with the template I'm using.

The error LaTeX Error: Command \openbox already defined. is due to the loading order of amsthm and newtxmath. The correct order is
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

However, in your case the cls file preloads newtxmath, so you are not permitted to load amsthm in the main TeX file.
Solution
Pass option amsthm to newtxmath to load the amsthm package and define a new theorem style using \newtheoremstyle.
\PassOptionsToPackage{amsthm}{newtxmath}
\documentclass{optica-article}

\journal{opticajournal} % for journals or Optica Open

\articletype{Research Article}
\newtheoremstyle{yly}
                {3pt} % upper space
                {3pt} % lower space
                {\rmfamily} % main font
                {0pt} % indentation
                {\bfseries} % heading font
                {.} % punctuation
                {1em} % space after heading
                {}
\theoremstyle{yly}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[section]
...
\section{Introduction}

\begin{problem}
    hello
\end{problem}
...


